# Jquery Live Notification

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i have a big problem with my project.

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.deutschebahn.com/fasta/v2/facilities? 
type=ELEVATOR&stationnumber=1401",
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
"authorization: Bearer XXX",
"cache-control: no-cache"
),
));
$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

$result = json_decode($response, true);

$lift_status[4] = $result['5']['state'];
$lift_status[5] = $result['5']['state'];
$lift_status[6] = $result['6']['state'];
$lift_status[7] = $result['6']['state'];
$lift_status[9] = $result['7']['state'];
$lift_status[10] = $result['7']['state'];
$lift_status[11] = $result['2']['state'];
$lift_status[12] = $result['2']['state'];
$lift_status[13] = $result['3']['state'];
$lift_status[14] = $result['3']['state'];
$lift_status[15] = $result['4']['state'];
$lift_status[16] = $result['4']['state'];
$lift_status[17] = $result['0']['state'];
$lift_status[18] = $result['0']['state'];
$lift_status[19] = $result['1']['state'];
$lift_status[20] = $result['1']['state'];
```

These are lifts, and the $lift_status[4] is the track from a station. The Result will be ACTIVE or INACTIVE.

I have a second Page with a list of some tracks.

For example (state = ACTIVE)

```
<span class="badge badge-lg badge-primary">Track 4</span>
<span class="badge badge-lg badge-primary">Track 11</span>
<span class="badge badge-lg badge-primary">Track 7</span>
<span class="badge badge-lg badge-primary">Track 20</span>
```

And now (state = INACTIVE

```
<span class="badge badge-lg badge-danger">Track 4 <i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i></span>
<span class="badge badge-lg badge-danger">Track 11 <i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle</span>
<span class="badge badge-lg badge-danger">Track 7 <i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle</span>
<span class="badge badge-lg badge-danger">Track 20 <i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle</span>
```

Has anyone an idea how i can solve my problem?

Thanks in advance
Dennis

Comment: What exactly is the problem? You've posted some things but not told us what the problem is that you need help correcting.

Answer (score 0):

I want to change (live) the

```
<span class="badge badge-lg badge-primary">Track 4</span>
```

to

```
<span class="badge badge-lg badge-danger">Track 4 <i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i></span>
```

when the state change from ACTIVE to INACTIVE